# listView item click event not firing

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclick, onclicklistener

I am having an issue with using a listview that when I click it nothing is happening.  I would like for it when I click the listview item to make a toast so I know it is being clicked.  I have been trying/researching for a while and nothing.  Would anybody mind taking a look to see if I am missing something I just am overlooking?  Many thanks in advance!

Here is my class:

```
public class MyCar extends Activity {

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
public ListView mylistView;
String carInfo;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mylistAdapter;
ArrayList<String> arrayListCar = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mycar);
    mylistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    arrayListCar = new ArrayList<String>();
    //Just had to remove setting this adapter 2 times.  Took out line below to fix.
    mylistView.setAdapter(mylistAdapter);

    mylistView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

            String item = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    carInfo = trySomethin();
    fillList();
}

public void fillList() {
    String make = "";
    String model = "";

    String[] pieces = carInfo.split("\"");
    make = pieces[3];
    model = pieces[7];

    ArrayList<String> carList = new ArrayList<String>();
    carList.add(make + " " + model);
    // Create ArrayAdapter using the car list.
    mylistAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyCar.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, carList);

    mylistView.setAdapter(mylistAdapter);
    mylistAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

Comment: You do not see the `Toast`?

Comment: Yes, I am not seeing the toast.  When I click it the listview stays there and I can click it 10 times and nothing happens.

Comment: Wow guys, I am sorry to waste  time I did not see I was setting the adapter to mylistView 2 times.  Removed the one in the onCreate and it now works.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

if you have any elements on listview item change this for them

```
android:focusable="false"
```

and if you are changing any elements visibility on runtime you have to handle focus programatically each time you change its visibility.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Try this 


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

           // ListView Clicked item index
           int itemPosition     = position;

           // ListView Clicked item value
           String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);              
            // Show Alert 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
              "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
             .show();

          }
        });
```